I created a simple Macro to loop through all tables, but the macro is skipping some tables. Why?
I created this Macro to fix my tables on this Word document. I use a design software tool that creates these reports which I try to clean up using macros. I first run autofit to contents and then autofit to window. I loop these commands through all tables. Some tables in these documents get missed (always the same tables) and I have to edit them manually afterwards.
Here is my VBA code: I suspect the problem is a format for some of the tables in my document, but I don't know how to fix this.
Sub AdjustTablesAutofit()
    Dim tbl As Table
    
    ' Loop through all tables in the document
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        ' Autofit to Contents
        tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitContent
        ' Autofit to Window
        tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    Next tbl
    
    MsgBox "Tables have been adjusted successfully!", vbInformation
End Sub


A snapshot of the skipped table could be helpful for troubleshooting.

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f79af566fae52d5e7023870540035c4620241127164254/68dc5b?t_exp=1732984974&t_lsid=1eff0d30-d615-4e70-935f-a8273d6869a1&t_network=link&t_rid=ZW1haWx8Njc0NzRjMGZiNjM1NTFjNmY2ZmNlZjUz&t_s=download_link&t_ts=1732725825

Here is an example copy of a Word report. The tables on page 5 are not being edited by the Macro

Add tbl.Select right after the For loop starts and run the code in debugging mode (step by step). This will allow you to observe how the tables on page 5 are being selected and formatted by the script. Also, why are both wdAutoFitContent and wdAutoFitWindow used in your script? What is the specific output you are aiming to achieve?

The table on Page 5 does get re-sized (if I first shrink it down then the code makes it wider)  Maybe the result is just not what you expect it to be?

The 2nd table on page 6 (I incorrectly called for page 5 previously) still has wrapped text. If I Autofit to content first, then it eliminates the wrapped text (where possible) and then Autofit to window creates uniform sized tables.

If I run the debug tool (Step Into) and keep hitting F8, then the Macro runs through the entire document and fixes all the tables. No problem with the code. If I simply run the Macro, then not all tables get fixed. I'm utterly confused.
